# How to test whether an R function is defined to accept its input as `...`

Tags: r, function

What would be a proper way to programmatically test whether a given R function accepts its main input as dot-dot-dot or via named argument?

For example, consider the difference between `max()` and `log()`. Whereas `max()` is defined to take `...`, `log()` expects a numeric vector `x`.

How can I test a function for that difference?

For example:

```r
# ddd stands for dot-dot-dot
is_main_input_ddd(max) # true
is_main_input_ddd(log) # false
```

Comment: `formals(args(max))` ? `formals` doesn't work for for primitive functions, but formals/args seems to work for all

Comment: Adding to what @rawr says, the `formals` docs suggest calling something like `formals(args(max))`. If you wrap that in `names`, you'll get back `"..."` as one of the argument names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments of @rawr and @camille:

```r
is_main_input_ddd <- function(.f) {
  names(formals(args(.f)))[1] == "..."
}

is_main_input_ddd(max)
#> [1] TRUE
is_main_input_ddd(log)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Do you only want to detect whether `...` is the *first* argument, or whether it is one of the arguments? Off the top of my head, `httr::GET` is an instance where `...` won't be the first argument, so your function will return false

Comment: @camille, yes I'm mostly concerned about the first argument because the context of this question is about using Rscript. The way you provide arguments input to Rscript via command line is critical. As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841223/6105259).

Comment: Hmmm that seems like either a specific use case or a slightly different situation. Either way it's a good function, just had that potential shortcoming